# Having problem indexing images in the Github Pages

Tags: html, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I'm having a problem indexing images in a Github Pages repository. I've already created a folder in my repository that I am using as root for my Github pages.

The Markdown I have used to embed my image is as follow:

`![Histograma de Balanço](/Imagens/Hist%20Balance.png)`

However, when I go to my Github Pages site, the images failed to load:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it? I have tried to read Markdown cheat sheet and other relevant documents but I have no luck making it working.

Comment: Can you give us a link to your Github pages URL that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: sure! here you can access my page: https://luiz-faro.github.io/Luiz-Portfolio/

Comment: here is the repo that i'm using for this aplication as well: https://github.com/Luiz-Faro/Luiz-Portfolio

Comment: You're trying to link to `https://luiz-faro.github.io/Luiz-Portfolio/Imagens/Hist%20Balance.png`, but you're actually linking to the non-existent `https://luiz-faro.github.io/Imagens/Hist%20Balance.png`. Take the `/` off the start of the image URL.

Comment: Huge thaks bro, that worked! Was simple as that hahahahah now going to finish my portfolio